# How do I change convert_option based on user input for Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I am currently using rails 3.1 and paperclip. I basically want a way so that I can blur a image only when the user ask to blur the image. I believe that -blur will do that with convert_options. However, I am getting stuck at how to send something from the view to paperclip in my art model. Is it possible to do a if statement inside has_attached_file for paperclip? So I can specify that if the user want to blur, I will have a certain convert_option parameter? Will attr_accessor work in sending what the user put in the checkbox to model? I tried looking all over the internet but can't seem to find anything.

Thank you a lot for your help

Kane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use lambda to solve this as paperclip accepts lambda